# Jenkins declarative pipeline throws org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified getAt method

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have defined a shared library in Jenkins:

```
import com.codependent.jenkins.pipelines.Utils

def call(List<String> mavenGoals){
  def processedMavenGoals = mavenGoals.join ' '
  pipeline {
    agent any
  ...
}
```

If i call this from my project's Jenkinsfile like this it works ok:

```
#!groovy
@Library('jenkins-pipeline-shared-library-example') _
buildPipeline(['clean', 'install'])
```

However if I omit the parethesis as Groovy syntax allows:

```
#!groovy
@Library('jenkins-pipeline-shared-library-example') _
buildPipeline ['clean', 'install']
```

The execution shows the folloing exception. Why?

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified getAt method buildPipeline[java.util.ArrayList]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetArray(SandboxInterceptor.java:451)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$10.call(Checker.java:413)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetArray(Checker.java:418)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getArray(SandboxInvoker.java:45)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ArrayAccessBlock.rawGet(ArrayAccessBlock.java:21)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:3)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
```

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Have you found the solution yet? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, no solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had a similar issue after updated jenkins.

In my case the stacktrace also showed a `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException[...]`

## Reason

Jenkins has a security plugin that blocks certain method calls in Jenkinsfile s.

## Solution

To allow these calls that sometimes are harmless:

1. Go to: http://JENKINS_HOST/scriptApproval/ ( [Official Documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/) )
2. Approve the action that has been denied in the Jenkinsfile
   [image]
3. Rerun the failed build to see Jenkinsfile work

Answer (score 0):

In most cases <JENKINS_SERVER_URL>/scriptApproval should be enough. However there are cases when the forbidden method **does not appear in /scriptApproval** due to some reasons. Some of them are explained here: [Why-am-I-unable-to-see-a-method-in-In-process-Script-Approval](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016527252-Why-am-I-unable-to-see-a-method-in-In-process-Script-Approval-).

In such case you can try either programmatically force the method approval (see the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48234868/4807875) or manually update the $JENKINS_ROOT/scriptApproval.xml file on the Jenkins server. The latter will require root permissions and Jenkins server restart to take effect (the option "Reload Configuration from Disk" will not work).

P. S.: I did not test how it works with the [BlackList](https://github.com/jenkinsci/script-security-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/sandbox/whitelists/blacklist) methods.