# Execute groovy script from pipeline throws RejectedAccessException

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following script in a .gsh file:

```
build = Thread.currentThread().executable
String jobName = build.getEnvVars()["JOB_NAME"]
println "JOBNAME: " + jobName
```

When I execute this script within a normal freestyle project it does work fine in the step `Execute system Groovy script` output: `JOBNAME: playground/Testing`.

However if I execute the same script within a pipeline:

```
stage('Test') {
 steps {
  script {
   jobName = load 'C:/Tools/getTag.gsh'
  }
 }
}
```

I do get an RejectedAccessException.

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field java.lang.Thread executable
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.unclassifiedField(SandboxInterceptor.java:426)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:410)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:357)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:8)
```

How can I execute this script within the pipeline?

Notes:

- I can't approve it like [Jenkins RejectedAccessException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429657/jenkins-declarative-pipeline-throws-org-jenkinsci-plugins-scriptsecurity-sandbox) as it is already approved and works within the freestyle project.

Comment: It is possible that the `build` variable is already used by Jenkins and available to you. Try getting your build with `myBuild = build.getClass()`

Comment: Also, you should have the job name already provided to you by jenkins, just do `println( "${env.JOB_NAME}")`